# Query : equals values are not equals

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

Welcome

I am using Laravel 6.6.2 and I want to execute my query. That work if I execute my query in MySql-workbench (with sql fromat).
I have this following problem, 2 equals values are not equal.

```
$myId = DB::table("masterTable")
    ->select("ass_group_user.group_pgr_id","group.pgr_id")
    ->leftJoin("user","user.status_flag","=","gen_client.status_flag")
    ->leftJoin("group","group.pgr_foreign_key","=","gen_client.id")
    ->leftJoin("ass_group_user","ass_group_user.user_id","=","user._id")
    ->Where("user.name","=","myName")
    ->Where("ass_group_user.group_pgr_id","=","group.pgr_id")
->get();
```

Return empty array. 
If I actually write that instead of "Where("ass_group_user.group_pgr_id","=","group.pgr_id")"

```
->Where("ass_group_user.group_pgr_id","=",6)
->Where("group.pgr_id","=",6)
```

return what I want. 
**Both of them are Int.**

Thank you

Comment: Does both fields have the same datatype? What exactly?

Comment: Both of them are Int(10) with te same parameters. 
If I execute my query in Workbench or phpmyadmin that works

Comment: can you verify that it is actually the same query?  i.e. `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` is the same query you run in workbench?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

If both the columns are ints, I don't see how this could happen.  However, if they were strings, you could have situations such as this:

```
'06' = 6
'006' = 6
```

but:

```
'06' <> '006'
```

That is because in a mixed comparison with a number and a string, the string is converted to a number.

Comment: Both of them are Int(10) with te same parameters. 
If I execute my query in Workbench or phpmyadmin that works